# Why is orthogonal projection not always multiplication by a diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, projection, projection-matrices

Suppose I have a vector $v$ which I want to orthogonally project onto a subspace $S.$ The subspace is defined as the space spanned by the columns of a matrix $A.$  I could do this by constructing a projection matrix $P$ via the common formula $P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T,$ and then computing the projection via $Px.$

However, we know that there exists some basis for the subspace $S$ such that the projection operator is diagonal, having diagonal elements equal to zero or one.  We also know that orthogonal projection is independent of basis.  So I should also be able to compute the projection via $Px,$ where $P$ is diagonal.

This seems strange to me - note that I didn't have to cast $x$ in any new basis, only $P.$  It would imply that projecting a vector onto a subspace can *always* be reduced to multiplication by a simple diagonal matrix.

I am guessing that my error is in asserting that $x$ need not be written in terms of the basis which diagonalizes $P.$  But  I don't see why.

Comment: You write everyting in terms of the same basis: input vector, matrix, output vector.

Comment: The fact that a projection is orthogonal is independent of basis. What the corresponding matrix looks like is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this reasoning a change-of-basis matrix should always just be an appropriately-sized identity matrix, since it represents the identity map. Just as a vector exists independently of a choice of basis, but its *representation* as a coordinate tuple is certainly basis-dependent, the linear map that is this projection exists independently of choice of basis, but its representation as a matrix is basis-dependent.